# Инициализация базы данных в magento

Tags: php, cms, magento

Суть задания состоит в том, чтоб сделать инициализацию бд, точнее таблицы `ds_news_entities`. С `magento` работаю первый раз, потому и возникло затруднение (версия `Full Release - ver 1.9.2.4`) .

В директории `app/code/local/TestModule` создаю директорию своего модуля `News`

Сразу же в конфиге `app/code/local/TestModule/News/etc/config.xml` задаю настройки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TestModule_News>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </TestModule_News>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Следующим шагом создаю конфиг в `app/etc/modules/TestModule_News.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TestModule_News>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TestModule_News>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Потом в директории `app/code/local/TestModule/News/sql` создаю поддиректорию `testmodulenews_setup` и в ней файл установки `install-0.0.1.php`:

```
$installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("CREATE TABLE ds_news_entities (
        `news_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
        `created` DATETIME,

        PRIMARY KEY (`news_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");

    $installer->endSetup();
```

Послу этого редактирую уже ранее созданный файл настройки `app/etc/modules/TestModule_News.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TestModule_News>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TestModule_News>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <testmodulenews_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>TestModule_News</module>
                </setup>
            </testmodulenews_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

По идеи после обновления страницы должна создаться запись в таблице `core_resource`, соответствующая названию создаваемой таблицы.

Но после перезагрузки страницы возникает ошибка:

> ## 0 /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
> Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
> Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
> Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE ds...', Array) #5
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE ds...', Array) #6
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(423):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE ds...') #7
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(693):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('CREATE TABLE ds...') #8
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(675):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->multi_query('CREATE TABLE ds...') #9
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(932):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->multiQuery('CREATE TABLE ds...') #10
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/local/TestModule/News/sql/testmodulenews_setup/install-0.0.1.php(17):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->run('CREATE TABLE ds...') #11
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(624):
> include('/home/vitaliy/h...') #12
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '',
> '0.0.1') #13
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.0.1') #14
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates() #15
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates() #16
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() #17
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/app/Mage.php(683):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #18
> /home/vitaliy/hosts/magento.dev/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> ## 19 {main}errord

**В чем я ошибся ? Или что то делаю не так ?**

**Прошу подсказки(**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы должны создать resource model т.е. в конфиги прописать

```
        <your_module>
            <class>You_Module_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>your_module_resource</resourceModel>
        </your_module>
```

далее конфигурируем resource model

```
        <your_module_resource>
            <class>Your_Module_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <yourtable>
                    <table>your_table</table>
                </yourtable>
            </entities>
        </your_module_resource>
```

далее в конфиге прописываем resource setup

```
    <resources>
        <your_module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Your_Module</module>
            </setup>
        </your_module_setup>
    </resources>
```

обращаем внимание что `your_module_setup` это название поддиректории директории sql.

далее создаём нашу модель

```
class Your_Module_Model_Model extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    protected $_dataLayer = null;

    function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('your_module/yourtable');
    }
}
```

теперь создаём директорию `Resource` в директории `Model`. и в нём файлик ресурс модели

```
class Your_Module_Model_Resource_Model extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('your_module/yourtable','entity_id');
    }
}
```

и последним штрихом esоздаём `Collection`, в директории Resourceсоздаём поддиректорию с именем файла ресурса `Model`в нашем случае, довольно плохое название, вы уж извините. И в этой директории создаём фаил `Collection.php`

```
class Your_Model_Model_Resource_Model_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    /**
     * init collection
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('your_module/yourtable');
    }

}
```

я специально не стал приводит полный рабочий пример и название те которые вы дали. К сажелению, для работы с magento надо знать английский как минимум на техническим уровне. В решение вашей задачи поможет данная статья http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/ и мой ответ. Удачи вам, и если есть какие то затруднения с магентой, пожалуйста пишите на ru.stackoverflow.com я постараюсь оперативно отвечать. Так как magento довольна тяжела в понимание архитектуры, то лучше задать вопрос и получить ответ чем изобрести функционал который уже есть. Удачи вам!

Comment: спасибо большое ) Очень мне помогли!